# Как убрать подсветку в GridView

Tags: android, gridview, java

Есть `GridView`. Когда мы прокручиваем его элементы (вверх или вниз, не важно), то дойдя до края `GridView` появляется синяя подсветка по краю до которого прокручивали, то бишь сверху и снизу в зависимости от того куда мы листаем.

Как это убрать?

Картинка:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все работает. Но нужно сделать так:

```
 magazineGrid.setAdapter(new YearsAdapter());
 magazineGrid.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

То бишь:

1. Не используем атрибут в xml вообще, ибо он не работает.
2. Для GridView устанавливаем адаптер и затем вызываем метод setOverScrollMode. В доке к методу написано, что данная опция View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER будет работать только если вьюшка может скроллится. Впринципе, думаю можно вызвать метод и до установки адаптера. Скорее всего это не принципиально.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Или

```
GridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

или

```
<ListView android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

или

```
<ListView 
  android:overscrollHeader="@null" 
  android:overscrollFooter="@null" />
```

Comment: Нет, это не то. Данный атрибут убирает подсветку при таче на элементе. И да, он и так установлен.

Comment: android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: Нет, не то.

Comment: 2а последних должно помочь

Comment: GridView поддерживает по идеи только android:overScrollMode="never". Но и это не помогло. Проверяй плиз решения перед ответом.

Comment: setOverscrollFooter(null) and setOverscrollHeader(null)

Comment: У меня GridView. Там нет таких методов или я что-то не так понял?